# How to display an image in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an android app using java and Firebase. In that I'm using a recycler view to display the images and other contents which are stored in Firebase database. When I run the program the other contents are displaying correctly but the image is not showing. This is my first time developing an android application so I'm confused.

Any help you can provide me to get this to work would be great.

Here is my code,

Adapter class

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyMessageHolder> {

    private StorageReference storage;

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<profile> Messages;

    public MessageAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<profile> p)
    {
        context = c;
        Messages =p;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyMessageHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyMessageHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_card_view,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyMessageHolder holder, int position) {
        profile prof = Messages.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(Messages.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(Messages.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.date.setText(Messages.get(position).getDate());
        //Picasso.get().load(Messages.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(prof.getImage())
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Messages.size();
    }

    class  MyMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView name,description,date,time;
        ImageView image;
        public MyMessageHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hDescription);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hDate);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hTime);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hImage);

        }
    }
}
```

Main activity class

```
 class MainActivityHomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<profile> list;
    MessageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    profile p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(profile.class);
                    list.add(p);
                }
                adapter = new MessageAdapter( MainActivityHomePage.this,list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivityHomePage.this, "something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Model class

```
package com.eNotification.getnotify;

public class profile {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String date;
    private String image;

    public profile() {
    }

    public profile(String title, String description, String date, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

card view layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/silver"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/lightSilver"
                android:hint="Title"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hTime" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/lightSilver"
                android:text="Description"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hDate"
                android:layout_width="136dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:background="@color/lightSilver"
                android:text="Date"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/hTime"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hTime"
                android:layout_width="116dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:background="@color/lightSilver"
                android:text="Time"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/hDate"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hImage"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.834" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Recycler view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You get images from firebase correctly?

Comment: what is the value of prof.getImage?

Comment: log result of prof.getImage all tell me what it is

Comment: Please a log statement and tell us what the value of `prof.getImage()`. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I wrote this code by referring this video https://youtu.be/vpObpZ5MYSE

Comment: ,@MohammadMoeinGolchin I don't know. My be the problem is in image downloading part.